# IOS Camera/Microphone constant usage message

Tags: ios, camera, privacy

I am having trouble understanding the description from apple to access/use the camera in Ios devices.
They wrote

> iOS requires that your app provide static messages to display to the
> user when the system asks for camera or microphone permission: If your
> app uses device camera [...]
> ([Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/requesting_authorization_for_media_capture_on_ios))

So do I always need to display a symbol when using the camera? Like a recording flashing?
Or does the "static message" refers the first request for accessing the camera?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you are referencing is referring to the key/values that you add to your `Info.plist` that get shown to users when requesting permission to access the calendar or microphone. This presentation is done automatically by the system when you ask for permission to access those devices (via `requestAccess` for example -- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624584-requestaccess). The alert gets displayed when the app asks the user for permission and then does not get shown again.

You don't need to "display a symbol when using the camera" in any version of iOS. However, in iOS 14, you *will* see indicator dots in the status bar (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211876) that the system adds when these resources are being used.